# @Query is not working with r2dbc and postgres

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive, r2dbc-postgresql

```
@Repository
public interface XYZRepository extends R2dbcRepository<XYZ, XYZPK> {

    @Query(value = "select * from xyz\n" +
            "right join (select max(capture_date) capture_date from xyz) as t using (capture_date)\n" +
            "where id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    Flux<XYZ> getLatestById(@Param("id") String id);

}
```

I was expecting it to return just latest from database but it returning all entries by id and  I tried renaming it to "getLatestXYZ" then getting error "No property 'getLatestXYZ' found for type 'XYZ'"

Answer (score 0):

There is no query method which parses *getLatest*. You can use getFirst or getTop to sort the results and get top results (by asc or desc order). For example, `findTopByIdAndOrderByCaptureDateDesc(Long id)` . This will only filter the rows with id and get row with max Capture Date. If we need to filter the row with max(capture_Date) then @Query option can be used as you showed or shown below. Here method name will not be parsed as Query annotation takes priority.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM xyz  WHERE m.id = :id AND m.capture_date= (SELECT MAX(e.capture_date) FROM xyz e)", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<XYZ> findByIdWithMaxCaptureDate(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion and did with 2 queries, though my job is done still I didn't like the fact we can't ran custom queries like with jdbc :(. Also Max is not exist and I did with orderby and top.